# ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "1658792421"

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to convert and epoch to a string on PostgreSQL and I get the following error:

```
ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "1658792421"
```

The query is the following:

```
SELECT to_timestamp('1658792421', 'DD-MM-YYYY');
```

Not really sure why this happens.

I'm using PostgreSQL 13.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a number, not a string if you want to convert the dreaded Unix epoch. But that version of `to_timestamp` doesn't accept a format mask (as you are passing a number).

```
SELECT to_timestamp(1658792421)
```

If you want to format that `timestamp` value, use `to_char()`

```
SELECT to_char(to_timestamp(1658792421), 'DD-MM-YYYY')
```